# DB2 create staging table for MQT(Materialized Query Table) for incremental refresh

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

How can I create a staging table for an MQT (Materialized Query Table)?

The goal is to use an incremental refresh (instead of a full refresh)

This is with DB2 on an IBMi

I was following this article
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sample.doc/doc/clp/s-tbast-db2.html

I am able to create an MQT

When I try to follow the example to create the staging table I receive an error

For example,

MQT creation for XXLIB.SALES:

```
create table XXLIB.SALES as 
(select Company, Territory, SUM(Sales) 
From XXLIB.HISTORY Where Company = 1 Group by Company, Territory)
data initially deferred refresh deferred maintained by user
```

Then for the staging XXLIB.SALES_S

```
CREATE TABLE XXLIB.SALES_S FOR XXLIB.SALES PROPAGATE IMMEDIATE;
```

Here is the error message

> SQL State: 42601 Vendor Code: -104 Message: [SQL0104] Token . was not
>   valid. Valid tokens: . Cause . . . . . :   A syntax error
>   was detected at token ..  Token . is not a valid token.  A partial
>   list of valid tokens is .  This list assumes that the
>   statement is correct up to the token.  The error may be earlier in the
>   statement, but the syntax of the statement appears to be valid up to
>   this point. Recovery  . . . :   Do one or more of the following and
>   try the request again: -- Verify the SQL statement in the area of the
>   token .. Correct the statement.  The error could be a missing comma or
>   quotation mark, it could be a misspelled word, or it could be related
>   to the order of clauses. -- If the error token is ,
>   correct the SQL statement because it does not end with a valid clause.
>
> Processing ended because the highlighted statement did not complete
>   successfully

Comment: Maybe you accidentally shared the wrong link https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzsetep.htm
That is for SET ENCRYPTION PASSWORD

Comment: Are you saying this is different for Db2 on IBMi?

The staging table creation logic, ie
CREATE TABLE X_S FOR X PROPAGATE IMMEDIATE;

Comment: Precisely. Use *only* the syntax offered by your server-platform and version. Use *only* the matching documentation for that server-platform and version.  Yes, a better URL might be https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzajq/rzajqmqt.htm   along with the relevant create table statement.

Comment: Thanks mao, please give a link for creating the staging table

Comment: What makes you believe that your i-version supports that functionality for MQT ?  In the Knowledge-Center, click 'Change version of product' to choose the version that matches your server, then enter your search terms in the top right search box. Study what syntax is available on your platform+version.

Comment: Mao - refresh works on the MQT.  I believe there is a way to refresh part of an MQT instead of the whole thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Db2 for IBM i doesn't support all of the MQT functionality that Db2 for LUW does..

Db2 for i lacks system maintained MQTs along with incremental user maintained ones.

You'd need to roll your own solution on Db2 for i using triggers on the base table.

Your trigger could update the MQT immediately or write to your own "staging" table.  **Note**  This table is staging only in the sense that that's how your refresh process uses it.  You have to manually create it yourself, as far as Db2 for i is concerned, it's a completely stand alone table.

Personally, I've never bother with MQTs, instead an encoded vector index (EVI) with computed columns meets every need I've every considered. (Note that Db2 LUW doesn't have EVIs)

EVI's are system maintained, so the data is always up to date.

```
CREATE ENCODED VECTOR INDEX sales_fact_location_id_evi 
ON sales_fact(sale_location_id ASC) 
INCLUDE(SUM(sale_amount_measure))
```

The following IBM doc, [Accelerated analytics - faster aggregations using the IBM DB2 for i encoded vector index (EVI) technology](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-accelerated-analytics-db2-evi-tech/index.html), talks about using EVIs where other RDBMS might use a MQT.

**added**
Here's an EVI that would take the place of the MQT you're trying to create...

```
CREATE ENCODED VECTOR INDEX XXLIB.SALES 
ON XXLIB.HISTORY(Company, Territory)
INCLUDE(SUM(Sales))
```

The only downside to an EVI vs. a MQT, is that you can directly reference an MQT in a query, instead of depending on the DB to implicitly use it.  With an EVI, you are dependent on the DB to implicit use it.

Comment: For DB2 on an IBMi, is there a way to update a portion of an MQT with a refresh?
For example, add one day of sales data to the existing MQT each day

Comment: Sure, an MQT is just another table.... so something like `insert into mymqt select <...> from basetbl where trandate = current_date - 1 day`

Comment: but again, assuming you're looking at MQT for aggregation, sales per month, quarter, year, ect...an EVI is likely a much easier solution.

Comment: Charles, the insert technique works.  I was hoping to use a staging table though or some other way that would be easier to maintain vs a huge SQL statement.  A full refresh we can use SQL
`Refresh TABLE MyMQT`

Comment: so point the `insert` sub-select to your staging table instead of your base table...

Comment: Thanks Charles.  Not sure I understand how.  My syntax for creating the staging table did not work.  If the staging table is created, how do I tell the MQT to refresh based on that staging table (how do I connect them so an incremental refresh request works) vs just insert the day of information.  Inserting a day of info is still MUCH better than a request to refresh the whole MQT

Comment: I think the Charles' point is that you can't do it the way you want to, it is not supported in DB2 for i. The better way is to use an EVI which is unique to DB2 for i.

Comment: Charles 1) does the suggestion for an EVI change depending on the number of tables (and aggregates)?  Let's say an MQT is built from other joined tables to get sales history (i.e. header, detail, company, customer, vendor, etc) and totals sales, cost, profit, GP%, etc.  Something an MQT shines at is deriving a table from SQL, which in this case takes normalized data and flattens it out (denormalize) which can help performance for reporting

Comment: 2)  EVI approach sounds like on an ad hoc basis may not be the best fit.  For example, when using historical data, pre-totalling the values is pretty slick with an MQT and makes it easy for other teams to use/leverage even if they do not understand DB2.  Issue a refresh table command means other teams do not need to know the SQL used to create it.  It just works.  If we create an EVI, it may not be used in an adhoc SQL statement right?  That's up to SQE.   
However queries over an MQT, will always use that

Comment: Might consider a view that looks like the MQT you're thinking of.  Then you can create EVI's over the base tables used by the view that aggregate the data.  Visual Explain can tell you if your getting index only access for queries to the view.

Comment: Best solution IMHO, an ETL process to a actual star-schema data warehouse (data mart).  As the IBM article shows, EVIs still have an important part to play.